# How to use Selenium to fill a form field - input vs__search

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PeZH.png)

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"myModal\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("Andre Felipe");
```

I use the code above to fill in the field but it stays fixed. I've tried simulating a click and enter and it didn't work.

I tried to simulate a click and Enter and it didn't work.Selenium managed to type but I couldn't find a way to fix the data in the form field.

Comment: You mean to say, the element is not accessible? Is it throwing NoSuchElementException? If no exception is thrown, did you try clicking via Actions class?